# What is the depth reached by chess-AI agents on a regular computer?

Tags: reference-request, game-ai, chess

I'm looking for some **reference** for the number of lookahead steps typically used by chess agents (Stockfish / Leela Chess Zero / others?)

From a quick search, I found that the answer depends on:

1. complexity of position,
2. computer hardware/processor speed,
3. efficiency of software/graphics interface,
4. time given to the chess engine.

With somewhat mediocre hardware, a **depth around 15 ply's in one second** is typical.

The NPS value for the Stockfish engine: 49,473 kN/s (calculating 49,473,000 positions (nodes) per second).

Source:

1. https://www.quora.com/What-is-Stockfishs-depth-when-analysing-a-chess-position
2. https://chessify.me/blog/nps-what-are-the-nodes-per-second-in-chess-engine-analysis

Comment: Note, the NPS value will not help you. These engines all prune heavily, and go much deeper than the NPS and tree size would suggest.